# Predefine/Pre-render data in a dropdown from one to another in a table(HTML)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, dropdown

I have a table with two dropdows,(By selecting the first dropdown's letter M - it gives Moscow) with 'change' function.
But this working only for first row not the second 
What changes should be done to get it work in second row

```js
                $(function() { 
                $("#select1").change(function() {
                    $("#select2").val($(this).val());
                });
                });
```

```html
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th><select id="select1">
                <option>1day</option>
                <option value="1">Letter M</option>
                <option>3day</option>
                </select></th>
                <th><select id="select2">
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option value="1">Moscow</option>
                <option>Berlin</option>
                </select></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>
                <select>
                <option>1day</option>
                <option value="1">Letter M</option>
                <option>3day</option>
                </select></th>
                <th><select>
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option value="1">Moscow</option>
                <option>Berlin</option>
                </select></th>
                </tr>
```

Comment: **select1 and select2** field id must be unique

Comment: This is an example, usually there will be single id right?

Comment: can you share your exact code?

Comment: Because you havnt write event for second row.
you can give two more unique id and event just like first row or on single action you want to handle both dropdown you can use class rather than id.Thanks

Comment: You mean instead of 'id' use 'class' ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
                $(function() { 
                $("#select1").change(function() {
                    $("#select2").val($(this).val());
                });

              $("#select3").change(function() {
                    $("#select4").val($(this).val());
                });

                });
```

```html
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th><select id="select1">
                <option>1day</option>
                <option value="1">Letter M</option>
                <option>3day</option>
                </select></th>
                <th><select id="select2">
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option value="1">Moscow</option>
                <option>Berlin</option>
                </select></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>
                <select id="select3">
                <option>1day</option>
                <option value="1">Letter M</option>
                <option>3day</option>
                </select></th>
                <th><select id="select4">
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option value="1">Moscow</option>
                <option>Berlin</option>
                </select></th>
                </tr>
```